# I have the same group and want to test differences for two (unrelated) variables - Do I use Wilcoxon signed-rank test or Wilcoxon rank sum test?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I wonder if this is a case that it not clearly specified:

Typically, *Wilcoxon rank sum test / Mann–Whitney U test* is used for independent groups and testing the values of different variables against each other.
Typically, *Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test* is used for dependent groups (same group) and testing the values for the changes in one variable (like in time series study).

But which test is used when I want to test differences for the same group (the same people are asked) for two different variables (non-parametric)?
This is not clearly specifiable with the usual definition for these two tests.

For my question the following example: The same teachers are asked about how deeply (or not) they have integrated a specific topic in their courses (Virtual Reality and Data Mining).
Here I used a Wilcoxon rank sum test / Mann–Whitney U test with which I want to test if there is a significant difference between the two:

```
wilcox.test(Bothque$VR_integr, Bothque$DM_integr, exact = FALSE, correct = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you identify the two answers from a given person (so that the two answers from the same person *can* be paired)? Or are these answers anonymous so they can't be paired?

Comment: Hello Glen, yes they could be paired. These answers are within a group and I can see for each person n (the person themselves are anonymized) which answers (values) are given for which of the two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have correctly understood the situation, if you have the data so that it can be paired, you should do so, and use the paired analysis.