# Test(s) for comparing predictor quality for different features?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, predictor, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I applied a predictor to different numeric features from the same group of subjects (n>1000). The features have different ranges. Is it possible in this case to apply a statistical test to make a statement like "The predictor works better for feature A than for feature B"?

The Wilcoxon signed-rank test and Mann-Whitney-U test have been suggested to me but I am not sure whether they are really applicable in this case, or to what exactly. I have the (absolute) errors of the prediction and Pearson's r from the regression between the actual and predicted values.

Based on [the reply here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583620/i-have-the-same-group-and-want-to-test-differences-for-two-unrelated-variables), the data would still be considered paired as I have the value for each feature of the same subjects, meaning the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is applicable?

Two ideas I have in mind are:

1. Apply the Wilxocon signed-rank test (or Mann-Whitney-U test?) to the absolute percentage errors as they might be more comparable considering the different feature ranges (and there are no zeros in the data)
2. Scale the features to the same range before the prediction (sounds not so nice as it messes with the actual data and maybe distorts the results)

Would they be applicable, or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.